# Почему видео в Fancybox с youtube не загружается?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Видео в Fancybox с youtube не загружается. Появляется окошко загрузки и грузит до бесконечности.

```
<a class="fancybox_media" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NGZQ_0uB764"><img src="images/img_01.jpg" alt=""/></a>
```

Все необходимое подключил.

```
<!-- Fancybox -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" media="screen">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
<!-- Fancybox end-->
```

Вызвал:

```
$('.fancybox_media').fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',
            helpers : {
                media : {}
            }
        });
```

jQuery v@1.8.1

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Просто в папке в html файле не работает, так и грузит до бесконечности.

Интересно, что когда все html файлы загрузил на сервер все заработало.